# Нужна помощь с версткой на flex

Tags: flexbox

Помогите разобраться с версткой на flex. Не получается осуществить наложение .svg элементов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZRPBQq

```
<section class="hero">
<div class="flex">
       <div style="padding-right: 10px; width: 50%; position: relative;">
    <img style="top:110px; left:215px; position: absolute;" class="img-circle"  src="http://pershay.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/1.jpg" width="130px"/> 
    <img  style="top:40px; left:120px; position: absolute;" src="http://pershay.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/2.svg" width="330px"/>
    <img  style="top:0; position: absolute;" src="http://pershay.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/1.svg" width="400px"/>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-right: 10px; width: 50%;">
      <h1>Name Surname</h1>
      <h3><span class="ui-core-skill max">Java</span><span class="ui-core-skill mid">Scala</span><span class="ui-core-skill min">PostgreSQ</span></h3>
  </div>
</div>
</section>

<style>
.hero{
    background: #292e32;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 80vh;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;

}

.img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.hero h1{
    font: bold 60px "Arial", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hero h3{
    font: normal 21px "Arial", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.ui-core-skill {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-family: "Arial";
}

.mid:after {
    font-size: 50px;
    content: "\. . .";
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ed7b48 0%, #ed7b48 45%, #64463a 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    margin: 10px 10px;
}

.min:after {
    font-size: 50px;
    content: "\. . .";
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ed7b48 0%, #64463a 50%, #64463a 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.max:after {
    font-size: 50px;
    content: "\. . .";
    color: #ed7b48;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px){

.hero{
    min-height: 600px;
}

.hero h1{
    font-size: 44px;
}

.hero h3{
    font-size: 18px;
}

.hero a.btn{
    padding: 15px 20px;
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: flex как бы тут не причем, у вас с позиционированием img-ками проблемы

Comment: @user2736875 img поправила, а вот с блоками все равно беда

Comment: на `div` у которых `width: 50%` - `display:inline-block` или `float:left` задайте, также `width: 50%` с `padding` не будет влезать, надо будет `width: calc(50%-10px)` типо так сделать. Вам еще верстке учится и учится. Читай и смотрите позиционирование и каких видов бывает `display` и т.д.